# What permission to use instead of manage_pages for getting page for facebook?

Tags: facebook

I am writing application for getting reviews for particular page from facebook. I found that for getting reviews you need to ask user for manage_permission and you will get one token which can be use for further communications.

But, right now manage_pages permission is deprecated since May 2022, what is alternative for getting user page access token to get reviews.

Furthermore, here it says that we can get page access token and page id using [get page id](https://graph.facebook.com/%7Buser-id%7D/accounts?access_token=%7Buser-access-token%7D). I am passing user id and token which I store using facebook login, but, I am not getting any data related to page.

Thanks.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/permissions/reference/pages_read_user_content

Answer (score 0):

With regards to your question, you can request for pages manage posts permission.

Read Doc. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/permissions/reference/pages_manage_posts